# Nesting IAsyncEnumerable

Tags: c#

I am trying to work around the problem [Pass-through for IAsyncEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59876417/pass-through-for-iasyncenumerable). The best I have so far is to return `IAsyncEnumerable<IAsyncEnumerable<T>>` instead of `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, then to flatten it. I'm not thrilled about it, so I'm asking here for suggestions.

The underlying goal is to allow one to get portions of one's IAsyncEnumerable from child methods without going insane. The Counting() method below is my attempt.

I don't think it would be much trouble to design a recursive object in order to allow deeper nesting. But I still don't think I would like it much.

```
public static class AsyncEnumerables
{
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(IAsyncEnumerable<IAsyncEnumerable<T>> enumerables)
    {
        await foreach (var e in enumerables)
        {
            await foreach (var t in e)
            {
                yield return t;
            }
        }
    }

    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> Singleton<T>(T t)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
        yield return t;
    }
}

public class AsyncEnumerableTests
{
    public async IAsyncEnumerable<int> Children()
    {
        yield return 1;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        yield return 2;
    }

    public async IAsyncEnumerable<IAsyncEnumerable<int>> Counting()
    {
        yield return AsyncEnumerables.Singleton(0);
        await Task.Delay(100);
        yield return Children();
        yield return AsyncEnumerables.Singleton(3);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Counting_Counts()
    {
        var numbers = new List<int>();
        await foreach (var n in AsyncEnumerables.Flatten(Counting())) {
            numbers.Add(n);
        }
        Assert.Equal(4, numbers.Count);
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            Assert.Equal(i, numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things worth considering when you are about to design an API, which should either return an `IAsyncEnumerable<IAsyncEnumerable<T>>` or return an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`

### IAsyncEnumerable < IAsyncEnumerable < T > >

#### Pros

- It is flexible from the consumer point of view. It allows you to use a single or multiple consumer model
- In case of multiple consumers the throughput can be higher, because the parallel processing potential
- It allows to use different `Timeout`s for different providers
- It allows custom code injection between two `yield return` statements

#### Cons

- In case of single consumer the ingestion logic can be a bit more complicated (compared to the flatten version)
- Nested async loops can complicate the exception handling logic (and also the debugging)

### IAsyncEnumerable < T >

#### Pros

- It is easier to use for a single consumer
- If the multiple provider model is just an implementation detail then it can hide this information behind a good abstraction
- It provides easier error handling capabilities

#### Cons

- It is harder to support multiple consumers model
- It is harder to inject custom code between `yield return`s
- Spanning new processing based on different providers is impossible

If you are considering to provide a flattened API then I would suggest to check that package, which is called [System.Interactive.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async/). Inside this package there is a class called `AsyncEnumerableEx` which defines a [Merge](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/305d381dcc46c5966e7260e0959b3083846bf05f/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive.Async/System/Linq/Operators/Merge.cs#L13) function.